# Creating a dynamic HTML email pulled from SQL Server database

Tags: html, sql-server, vba, email

I'm trying to put together a newsletter that links to articles on a website through Visual Studio windows forms. I can successfully pull out the article links which are stored in a SQL Server database.

My problem is how to handle the rest of the HTML email, for example how can I store the rest of the HTML body, style tags etc without making my code a complete mess, I've tried breaking it up into several parts stored in several string variables but then realised

1. what a mess it made my code and
2. that I had no way to handle the double quotes within the email content

Basically I just need some advice on how to handle the HTML body content of the email to then add in my articles, which are pulled from a SQL Server database, into the HTML

Comment: try to narrow down the question because it is way too broad to answer with a so answer. what did you try so far? did you write any code or take any decision?

Answer (score 1):

Keep the static email text *outside* of your application; create a *template* file (or field in the db) using `{CONTENT} / {TITLE}` style placeholder strings, load the file and `replace("{CONTENT}", db_value)` for all the values you need.

There is also the built in [`MailDefinition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx) class from `System.Web` which does the same.